# How to POST data from a textarea form?

Tags: php, html

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$apikey='IGNORE-THIS-VARIABLE';

// All URLS to be sent are hold in an array for example
$urls=array('http://www.site1.com','http://www.site2.com/');

// build the POST query string and join the URLs array with | (single pipe)
$qstring='apikey='.$apikey.'&urls='.urlencode(implode('|',$urls));

// Do the API Request using CURL functions
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.example.com/api.php');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,40);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$qstring);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

My PHP code works, but here's the line I'm having issues with:

```
$urls=array('http://www.site1.com','http://www.site2.com/');
```

Basically I just want to have a text-area on my website where users can enter a list of URLs (one per line) and then it Posts it using the PHP code above.

My code works when I just have the URLs built into the code like you can see above, but I just can't figure out how to make it work with a text-area...  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the page your submitting from? how are you having the user input these urls on your form because i don't remember text boxes doing multi-line, only textarea

Comment: Yes, I am having users submit the URLs.  Sorry, I did mean a textarea.  The form is on `submit.php` and it's being posted to `api.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below (on the same php page):-

```
<form method = "POST">

<textarea name="urls"></textarea><!-- add a lable that please enter new line separated urls -->

<input type = "submit">

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['urls'])){
    $apikey='IGNORE-THIS-VARIABLE';

    // All URLS to be sent as new-line separated string  and explode it to an array
    $urls=explode('\n',$_POST['urls']); //Or $urls=explode('\\n',$_POST['urls']);
    // if not worked then 
    //$urls=explode(PHP_EOL,$_POST['urls']); 

    // build the POST query string and join the URLs array with | (single pipe)
    $qstring='apikey='.$apikey.'&urls='.urlencode(implode('|',$urls));

    // Do the API Request using CURL functions
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.example.com/api.php');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,40);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$qstring);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

Note:- you can separate the form and logic on two different pages. that's seay i think.

You can use text-area and then you have to then explode by `\n` or if not work then explode by `PHP_EOL` to the initial url string and rest the code is same as above

Comment: Works almost perfect, but can we make it a textarea where the URLs are separated by line?

Comment: @edward. You mean like tags ? Ability to add multiple ?

Comment: You should check for the server request method.

Comment: There are some useful jQuery tags plugin available which are user friendly so users don't need to click or enter manually while inputing values.

Comment: @Mit.agile i am unable to figure out  what you understand through question. what i understand is 1. user have one text-box where he will post urls by separating it with comma (then use my answer). 2. if user have textarea and adding urls with new lines in text-area then explode with either `\n` or `PHP_EOL` and use my code

Comment: Code works perfect, couldn't figure out why it wasn't working at first.  Of course, I copy/pasted your code and forgot to change example.com to my actual domain :(

Comment: Btw, any simple way to display a message when the form is submitted?  Just something like "thanks for your submission"?

Comment: yes you can .use echo for message showing or you can use some pop-up message code too.

Comment: @Anant actually i was mentioning the things from users prospective as we can not trust on users what they need to or have to input input or what they will input and we can not control over their input in that longer level and tell them to input values comma separated and so on so i was mentioning about the front part [HTML Part] by giving a user friendly interface using one of the jquery plugins available (http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/) so the users do not need to enter comma or hit enter and such .. and from the server side .. we can deal the rest from ourside based on the plugin we use.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to the form value as in bellow box is. any tag in HTML form have name attribute, assign name for any textarea, input or select tag.

```
<form method="post" name="first_form">
    <input type="text" name="url" value="" />
    <textarea name="note"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
```

In PHP you can the pass the value using two methods, $_GET or $_POST.
assign the tag name which you give for the HTML tag ($_POST['note'] or $_POST['url']) and also you can make it like an array $_POST.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST)){

    // display the posted values from the HTML Form
    echo $_POST['note'];
    echo $_POST['url'];

  }
?>
```

Your Code:

```
    $apikey='IGNORE-THIS-VARIABLE';

    // All URLS to be sent are hold in an array for example
    $urls=array('http://www.site1.com','http://www.site2.com/');

    // build the POST query string and join the URLs array with | (single pipe)
    $qstring='apikey='.$apikey.'&urls='.urlencode(implode('|',$urls));

    // Do the API Request using CURL functions
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.example.com/api.php');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,40);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$qstring);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```